# VirtualBox: Centos 6 - I can't find an option to roll back my snapshots anymore?

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I've been using Virtualbox for some years now and like the snapshot functionality. For some reason on my Centos workstation I can't find an option to roll back. I'm sure it was there but I don't know where its gone ?

[image: Screenshot of Snapshot]

On the screenshot above you can see in brackets a snapshot called (after ad installation

The help section says

"Your new snapshot will then appear in the snapshots list. Underneath your new snapshot, you will see an item called "Current state", signifying that the current state of your VM is a variation based on the snapshot you took earlier. If you later take another snapshot, you will see that they will be displayed in sequence, and each subsequent snapshot is derived from an earlier one:" for some reason I'm not seeing that?

As I say I've been using this for years and never had a problem so not sure why I can't see those snapshots now? How can I get that functionality back?

uname -ra
Linux workstation.localdomain 2.6.32-220.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 14 04:00:16 GMT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

rpm -qa | grep Virt
VirtualBox-4.1-4.1.8_75467_rhel6-1.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on an empty area of the menu bar (the same gray line as "File", "Machine", and "Help") and select "Show Toolbar".  On the right side of the toolbar, it will have two options, "Details" and "Snapshots".  I'm not sure if there's a keyboard short cut or what, but there doesn't seem to be any other (obvious) way of accessing the snapshots from the UI.